# Best practice to query items including their linked data

Tags: sql, database, database-design, amazon-redshift

A database contains a table that has a one-to-many relation to another table. The first table has many columns, the second ones just a few – for example like in this database design:

```
┌───────────────────┐
│item               │
├───────────────────┤
│id: BIGINT         │←┐
│name: VARCHAR(100) │ │
│ ...               │ │
│<many attributes>  │ │
│ ...               │ │
└───────────────────┘ │
                      │ 
┌───────────────────┐ │
│item_tag           │ │
├───────────────────┤ │
│item_id: BIGINT    │─┘
│name: VARCHAR(100) │
│color: VARCHAR(50) │
└───────────────────┘
```

What is the best practice to retrieve all *item* rows, together with their tag names and tag colors – e.g. to display them in a list of items with tags.

**Possible Solution 1**

Join both tables on item id:

```
SELECT * FROM item JOIN item_tag ON id = item_id;
```

Here is the problem that table *item* has many columns that contain large amounts of data, because each row in *item* would be present multiple times in the query result. Much data had to be transferred through the network to the client. Additionally the client would have to merge all rows with the same item data, to get the respective tags for each item.

**Possible Solution 2**

First the items are queried…

```
SELECT * FROM item;
```

…and afterwards the tags for each item are retrieved:

```
SELECT * FROM item_tag WHERE item_id = ?;
```

But this would require multiple separate SQL queries – one for each *item* row – which can be slow; also due to network latency of each query request.

**Possible Solution 3**

Both tables are queried once…

```
SELECT * FROM item;
SELECT * FROM item_tag;
```

…and the mapping of the tags to the items is done by the client.

Here the number of queries and the transferred data amount is the lowest possible, but additional processing effort on client side is nessesary. If just a subset of *item*s is queried, the query to select the *item_tag*s could be modified to return just the tags of the queried items.

---

Are there any other/better possible solutions for this? What is best way to go?

I would prefer solutions that work with the limited database features of [Amazon Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_SQLCommandRef.html), that has not so many fancy features, like array types.

Comment: If you want to select the lowest possible number of rows and avoid at all cost duplication, one way would be to concatenate the values from the item_tag table and grouping by the item id, in this way you will have one item with all the corresponding item_tag in one row. I can't tell you though how much is the gain to be honest.

Comment: It depends. As you've described it, probably 3. but it shouldn't be too much effort to try all three and measure it. If going for option 3, you can also consider sorting each result set by `item_id`, giving the client a straightforward merge join to materialize the objects.

Comment: Select * on an analytical DB like Redshift is discouraged. It makes much more sense to use it to find how many items you have with specific tag set or other "interesting" questions. Do you have a specific query that you want to optimize with Redshift?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @Guy: I used `*` just to keep the example query simple, in real world I would select a data sub-set. But basically the data should be retrieved to be displayed in a list (imagine a table with items, where the last column contains a list of the respective tags) that allows someone to skim through the *items*. Currently no table schema exists, I'm just thinking about one. Normally a document based DB would be suitable for this specific case – but cannot be used as there is other data-warehouse data, this data should be combined with.

Comment: You are not restricted to a single data store. Have the meta data (like tags) in one data store (MySQL or MongoDB) and your events/log data in Redshift.

Comment: @Guy Unfortunately a requirement is that both data sets can be queried in one query with the same query language.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which items to pick then you can create an index on item_id in the item_tag table and use the first solution. If on an average, each item has a lot many tags, this will save you looking up a lot of rows in the item_tag table. Otherwise, if you are too concerned about the amount of data being transferred and need the result for all the items, then solution 3 seems appropriate since minimum amount of data will be transferred but the joining logic will have to be implemented on client side. So, there is no best solution. It all depends on situation.